# Accessing a specific character in a char pointers string in C

Tags: c

I'm using `scanf` to read a string and put it into a `char*`.

```
scanf("%s", &str);
printf("%c",str);
```

It works fine but I don't know how to access a specific character in that string as I would with a char[]. I have been trying to increment the address:

```
str += 1;
```

I have been messing around a bit but all I get is the first character or segfaults or bus errors. Is it possible to work with that string without copying into a `char[]`?

Comment: How are you allocating the memory?  I'm guessing that you're trying to write to an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I am just doing that:

     char *str;
 scanf("%s", &str);
 str += 2;
 printf("%c",(str));

If I type 'TEST' I will get a 'V' in the standard output.

Comment: You need to put that information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
  It works fine but I don't know how to access a specific character in that string as I would with a char[]
```

Just dereference the pointer-array with [] and access the character at position "i"

```
str[i]
```

2)

```
I have been messing around a bit but all I get is the first character or segfaults or bus errors
```

Yes - the arrayname itself is a pointer to the first character of the string

Answer (score -1):

If str is declared as `char *` then this statement

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

is incorrect. There has to be

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

And the next statement

```
printf("%c",str);
```

is also incorrect. There has to be

```
printf("%c", *str);
```

If you want to output some other character in the character array using pointer `char *` then you can write either

```
printf( "%c", *( str + n ) );
```

or

```
printf( "%c", str[n] );
```

or even as

```
printf( "%c", n[str] );
```

where n some integer value that less then `strlen( str )`

Take into account that str shall point to some allocated memory. Otherwise the program will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user161794 It works with &str because the value of str and &str is the same though the types of the expressions are different.

Comment: char *str;

    scanf("%s\n", str);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
       printf("%c", str[i]);

...same with *(str + i)

Comment: Why the hell do you encourage users to use `scanf("%s", ...)`??

Comment: @user161794  Yes it is the same.